# XPath query returns no element if load HTML from string and cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, xpath

I make a GET request from page with curl like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "path to website");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$html = curl_execute($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($editPage);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

var_dump($xpath->query('//*[@id="maincolumn"]/div[1]/div[5]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]//input[1]'));
```

and it says that no element is found, of course, it exists in that webpage.

That webpage does not load any JS in order to render HTML elements. Those xpath I copied from Google Inspector, right click on element I care about, choose Copy -> Copy as XPath.

Why does it happens ? Why that element is not found ?

Comment: Try to remove `tbody` from XPath: `.../table/tbody/tr[1]...` -> `.../table//tr[1]...`. Also note that using XPath expressions from Google Inspector is not the best idea...

Comment: Well done. That `tbody` was added by Chrome by default.

Comment: I wrote in my pos that page, no Javascript is executed

Comment: Check the html structure. If there's only one form under maincolumn element then you can simplify your xpath to '//*[@id="maincolumn"]//input[1]'